# Android notification service not working/not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I want to have a service that runs forever and send notifications every day at 6pm, but for some reazon mi service stops working or something wrong happens after a few hours, and I don't have any notifications at 6pm.

Here is my code, I'm 100% sure my notifications data is there, I use a local database

```
class NotificationService : AppService() {

    private val timer: Timer = Timer(false)
    private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null
    private var isServiceStarted = false
    private var notifications = emptyArray<INotification>()
    private lateinit var notificationController: INotificationServiceController

    private val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        notificationController = adaptersBuilder.notificationServiceController
        startService()

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        isServiceStarted = false
        notificationController.setServiceState(ServiceStates.STOPPED.name)
        notificationController.onDestroy()
        timer.cancel()
    }

    private fun checkDBTask() {
        Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Checking db")
        notificationController.updateNotifications()
        notificationController.getTodayNotifications { notifications ->
            this.notifications = notifications.toTypedArray()

            val now = Calendar.getInstance()
            if (now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 18 && now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 1) sendNotifications()
        }

    }

    private fun startService() {
        if (isServiceStarted) return
        isServiceStarted = true
        notificationController.setServiceState(ServiceStates.STARTED.name)
        wakeLock = (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NotificationService::lock").apply {
                acquire(500)
            }
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isServiceStarted) {
                launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    checkDBTask()
                }
                delay(1*60*1000)
            }
            Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Notification service stopped")
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotifications() {
        val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val resultIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        resultIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        resultIntent.putExtra("data", "fromNotification")

        val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        notifications.forEach { notificationData ->

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationsValues.CHANEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.safin_icon)
                .setContentTitle(notificationData.title)
                .setContentText(notificationData.description)
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(notificationData.description))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build()
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(notificationData.movementId ?: 0, notification)
        }
    }
}
```

I used an alarm manager before, but that doesn't worked. So I try this.

Comment: It works if the app is open

Comment: You can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for this purpose.

Comment: Which is the difference between a service and a work manager?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager from what I see the work manager is used for api level 14 to 22, my application has at least 23

Comment: No. WorkManager works on latest android version. Its also backward compatible with previous versions down to api level 14. And for the answer to the previous question, background services no longer works on newer android versions. You have to use either a [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) or WorkManager for background work.

Comment: Oh thank you, I go to try it :D

Comment: Pay attention to the system that can stop the workmanager depending on how the OS has been implemented by the device constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services in android 8.0 can be killed and some times don't start again, the `WorkManager` is the right class for this type of tasks. So, I changed my notifications service to a `WorkManager`.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006 This guide help me a lot.